# Bash: Output of a command is written only to screen and not to another file while using tee, what could be the reason?

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, tee

In order to troubleshoot some ftp connection error, I've been instructed to write a bash script which will infinitely connect to a remote frp server and get one file from there.

```
ftpuser="ftpuser" 
ftppasswd="ftppasswd" 
ftpsrv="download.akamai.com" 
log="/var/log/test_ftp_akamai.log" 
function print_log { 
        echo $(date +'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') $* >> $log 
} 

while true 
do print_log "-----===== Start =====------" | tee -a $log 
/usr/bin/wget ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ftpsrv | tee -a $log 
sleep 2 | tee -a $log 
print_log "-----===== Done =====------" | tee -a $log 
done
```

The script works properly but the output of the `wget` line which is printed to screen is supposed to also be `tee`'ed to the log, but for some reason only it isn't being written to the log.

Example:

```
[root@sjorigin1 ~]# tailf /var/log/test_ftp_akamai.log 
25-02-15 02:10:31 -----===== Start =====------
25-02-15 02:10:33 -----===== Done =====------
25-02-15 02:10:33 -----===== Start =====------
25-02-15 02:10:35 -----===== Done =====------
```

Can you find the reason for the fact that it is not written to the log?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the `wget` output really on STDERR?  That would explain why it doesn't get sent through the pipe.  If that's the case you could try `... |& tee -a $log` (given a grown-up shell).

Comment: You are also using double redirection.  `print_log` appends to `$log` and then you pipe to `tee -a $log` as well.  The pipe will never receive any input so you could simply remove it; or for consistency, you could change the function so it just logs to stdout.  The whole thing would be more elegant if you just added `done | tee -a "$log"` at the end of the loop, rather than redirect every command inside the loop.  Then you can fix `wget` by just adding `2>&1` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that although the `echo` statements go to `STDOUT`, and thus get sent through the pipe to `tee`, the "output" you're seeing from the `wget` command is on `STDERR`, which doesn't.

This doesn't go through a pipe by default, going - as you saw - to `tty` instead.  If you want to send **both** `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a pipe's `STDIN`, you should use `|&`, eg

```
/usr/bin/wget ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ftpsrv |& tee -a $log
```

That works in bash and tcsh, if memory serves.  For bog standard sh it's a bit more work, but can still be done (though I can't off the top of my head remember how).

**Edit** (by Anthony, whose comment follows; thanks! - MadHatter):

The syntax for POSIX compatible shells (should also work for `sh`) would be:

```
/usr/bin/wget ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ftpsrv 2>&1 | tee -a $log
```

Comment: I can never remember off the top of my head either; it's quicker and easier to find relevant information in the dash manual.